# Giving the equation for graphs of fractional powers

Tags: graphing-functions

In Mathematics Methods we are learning the features of graphs of fractional powers. The equations of these graphs are in the form: $y=a\sqrt{x-b}+c
$
By simply analysing a graph with a hyperbola how can we determine the equation?

For example, a hyperbola passes through points $(-2,-1)$ and $(3,1/2)$. Hyperbola passes through the origin. Determine the equation

Comment: $y=a\sqrt{x-b}+c$ is (half of) a [parabola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola), not a [hyperbola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola).